# Data shows up in websocket response but not in resolved promise

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt + Express/Feathers to build an app, with the two communicating over a socket.io connection. Using feathers-vuex, I can easily make requests from my client to the backend, and the responses come back perfectly in the networks tab of chrome inspector, but in the resolved promise in my code, each returned object is `undefined`.

Websocket request:

`4235["find", "journals", {}]`

Websocket response:

```
4335[null, {total: 3, limit: 10, skip: 0,…}]
0: null
1: {total: 3, limit: 10, skip: 0,…}
  data: [{_id: "5af62077f2389a7490be22d6"}, {_id: "5af62094f2389a7490be22d7", some: "data"},…]
    0: {_id: "5af62077f2389a7490be22d6"}
    1: {_id: "5af62094f2389a7490be22d7", some: "data"}
    2: {_id: "5af66b3ae8c629789f35ead3", name: "john", surname: "doe"}
  limit: 10
  skip: 0
  total: 3
```

And this is what `results` looks like at the debugger:

```
{total: 3, limit: 10, skip: 0, data: Array(3)}
  data: Array(3)
    0: undefined
    1: undefined
    2: undefined
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
  limit: 10
  skip: 0
  total: 3
  __proto__:
    ...
```

This is the section of my Nuxt page where I'm making the request:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{journals}}</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="findThoseJournals()">
    Search Journals
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      journals: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('journals', {
      findJournals: 'find'
    }),
    findThoseJournals() {
      this.findJournals({query: {}}).then((results) => {
        debugger;
        this.journals = results.data;
      });
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

And for the record, when rendered, `results.data` looks like [null,null,null].

I'm completely lost as to what's causing this behavior. Why does the metadata carry over though the data itself doesn't (yet the *number* of entries still does)? What's happening between the websocket frame response and the promise that's causing specifically the data to disappear?

Comment: Where are you calling `findThoseJournals`? Could you show more of the component and the relevant Vuex module?

Comment: Added the relevant details! Only bits not shown are extra divs and <style> section.

Comment: I don't see the vuex action for `findJournals`...

Comment: It's part of a service module from feathers-vuex - here's a link to the source code for that, though: [link](https://github.com/feathers-plus/feathers-vuex/blob/master/src/service-module/actions.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Threw some debuggers in the `feathers-vuex` actions and realized I hadn't set my `idField` to `_id` in my feathersClient config.

Answer (score 1):

`.findJournals()` is asynchronous.  That means the method returns long before its result has been obtained.  You don't show us the code that calls `.findJournals()`, but the way you have it structured, there is no way for the calling code to access the `.journals` property because it won't be set yet when `.findJournals()` returns.  So, what you need to do is to return the promise and let the caller use that promise to get the result.

```
findThoseJournals() {
  // return promise
  return this.findJournals({query: {}});
}
```

Then, the caller will do this:

```
someObj.findThoseJournals().then(journals => {
    // use journals here
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand the difference between your example ( resolving a promise in a wrapper function) and resolving a promise within the same function. By definition, isn't the function waiting to return until the promise is resolved either way? I also may be super wrong about this, but it seems like the response _is_ making it in time, considering that the metadata is returned and the data array is correctly sized. Though I do see how it'd be possible for an incomplete bytestring to return an array of undefined objects whereas the complete version would have those objects in it.

Comment: I don't mean to sound unthankful or combative - I just want to make sure I'm catching any mistakes in my own reasoning about things.

Comment: @Cameron - No. That's the whole issue. The function returns immediately and the promise resolves some time later.  Promises don't block.

Comment: @Cameron - The whole point of promises is that the promise is returned immediately and then sometime later, the promise notifies its observers that the value is available.  That's why we use promises.  Promises don't block functions from returning until the value is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your the code for `findJournals` action in your Vuex store, I can only imagine that you are not returning the Promise inside the action. Take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6w97yx0yo3. If you do not `return` inside `loadSomeUsers`, the response you get back in the component is `undefined` instead of the desired payload.